# DataGridView override Painting to set font

Tags: c#, datagridview, fonts, styles

Im trying to Programaticly change the `DataGridViews` "Cell Header" font style
The Col headers have to be UpperCase and I want to assign a new font.
If someone has done this before I would appreciate your guidance here.

### Update

Actually the font changing works fine its just the `headerText.ToUpper()` I need help with

```
private void dataGridView1_Painting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
            //Something like this.
           foreach(DataGridViewColumnCollection c in grd.Columns) {
               c.ColHeading.Text = c.ColHeading.Text.ToUpper(); 
           }

            //or
            //header row only
            if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            { 
                e.CellStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 11.0f);
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                e.Value = e.Value.ToUpper(); //fails as its a read only object
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with this control, but browse other events.  May not be making this change early enough, and have better luck with an "earlier" event.

There may be events on the rows or columns themselves that you should be wiring up to to accomplish this.

IEnumerable's solution as per comment:

```
dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e) { e.Column.HeaderText = e.Column.HeaderText.ToUpper(); }
```

Comment: you were right, I was looing in the wrong area -       
`private void dataGridView1_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Column.HeaderText = e.Column.HeaderText.ToUpper();
        }
`

Comment: Put the tick marks(left of numeral 1 on keyboard) around `code` in comments.  You could also post your exact solution as an answer.

Comment: In a scenario like this, would I edit your post to put the solution, or create another Answer post, I would just rather give you the credit and points as you directed me to the solution.

Comment: IDK, I'll add it to answer :)